# "javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException" when decrypt data from database

Tags: java

I want to store data (encrypted with DES) and then take the encrypted data from database and present it as a list. But I have a problem. Here is the code.

```
    public void EncryptDemo(){
    try {
        FileInputStream keyfis = new FileInputStream("mainkey.key");
        byte[] encodedKey = new byte[keyfis.available()];
        keyfis.read(encodedKey);
        keyfis.close();
        Key KeyFromFile = new SecretKeySpec(encodedKey, "DES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        String text=txtToEncryptData.getText(), output;
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, KeyFromFile);
        DataDemo = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes());
        InsertIntoDataBase();
        //I store it as varbinary in database
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (BadPaddingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

    public void DecryptDemo(){
    try {
        FileInputStream keyfis = new FileInputStream("mainkey.key");
        byte[] encodedKey = new byte[keyfis.available()];
        keyfis.read(encodedKey);
        keyfis.close();
        Key KeyFromFile = new SecretKeySpec(encodedKey, "DES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, KeyFromFile);
        String sql = "{call SelectAll}";
        CallableStatement call = conn.prepareCall(sql);
        call.execute();
        ResultSet result = call.getResultSet();
        DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
        while(result.next()){
            DataDemo = result.getBytes("TestData");
            byte[] plainText = cipher.doFinal(DataDemo);
            String after = new String(plainText);
            model.addElement(after);
        }
        lstDecryptResult.setModel(model);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (BadPaddingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

The encrypt and storing is allright. But when I take data from database, I get this error when decrypt (at byte[] plainText = cipher.doFinal(DataDemo);)

```
Jul 19, 2013 11:40:05 AM databaseencryptdecryptdemo.MainGUI DecryptDemo
SEVERE: null
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher
```

Anyone have a solution for this???

Comment: What is your database?  If SQLite, store the encrypted data as a `blob`.  Whatever the DB is, you need to select a datatype that will store and return "pure binary" vs character or numeric data.

Comment: I use Microsoft SQL Server 2012 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. But I think it's not the best.

I changed the type of table `DataDemo` from varbinary to image and everything became alright. But my data size store in database is heavier (about 4 times) than the oigin data.

But at least I solved my problem.

Does anyone have a better solution? I willing to hear from you.

Answer (score 0):

You should divide `DataDemo` variable into 8 byte pieces.

```
public List<Byte[]> divideInto8(Byte[] bytes) {
    int length = bytes.length;
    List<Byte[]> returnValues = new ArrayList<Byte[]>();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i = i + 8) {
        Byte[] thebytes = new Byte[8];
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {

            thebytes[j] = bytes[i * 8 + j];
        }
        returnValues.add(thebytes);
    }
    return returnValues;
}
```

Comment: possibly there is a better solution but this is also a solution. i edited the answer. note:i did not test the code but it should be like that.